letters of recommendation computer science masters
Would it be appropriate to request a letter of recommendation from a faculty member who taught me a course outside of the computer science domain, given that my bachelor's degree is in biology and I am applying for a master's in computer science? Alternatively, would it make sense to seek a letter of recommendation from the principal investigator from a biology lab, even though their research area differs from the field I am pursuing in my master's program?

Your both options are from biology? What is the difference between the fields of your options? Do you want to select only one of these two options?

Yes, definitely. There's a whole branch of computer science that is computational biology. Such a letter could show that you really understand the biology side, which would lead to better research (even without that connection, such a letter could show that you have generally strong skills as a researcher and as a student). As a very simple example, think about the computer science that went into mapping the human genome. Obviously, lots of expertise from biology was required, and it was essential to have people who understood both the biology and the computer science. So such a letter could make you a much stronger applicant, depending on the program.
